# Can I establish a udp connection to a network device using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, qt, networking, udp

I have a custom imaging device to which I connect using ethernet network cable and communication goes over udp. That happens on Windows, with a Qt application. Porting that Windows application to macOS and Linux is something we are considering.

Qt certainly makes multi-platform development easier theses days. However I was thinking here, if we can make a web app (a web site) which can connect to that device it will be even better, right? With Qt we still need to do some adjustments to make things work across all OS. But a website running in the browser just works the same way no matter the OS. And looks like javascript just becomes more and more popular these days.

So, maybe is a dumb question, but would that be possible?

Would nodejs be used in this scenario?

Comment: Using JavaScript yes, from within a Webbrowser likely not.

Comment: Appreciate if you could be more verbose. If not in a web browser, where would I run the javascript?

Comment: _"if we can make a web app (a web site) which can connect to that device it will be even better, right?"_ I think no "website" surpasses well written native applications in any platform (both in versatility and user experience).

Comment: I mostly agree, however there are counter examples. I'm using draw.io for years without asking for something native. For specific cases I think web perhaps can do it.

Comment: Yes, web (meaning "via browser") can do a lot! Usually less than a native application, but it can be enough in some cases. Also, usually people don't want to install an app for occasional use. (I would hate bein forced to install an app to access StackOverflow, buy something or register a complaint somewhere). Both have proper use cases.